# InDesign CC GREP Help. Adding spaces around "+" (plus) symbol

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, grep

Should be simple but it's not.

This GREP expression works in the FIND/CHANGE PANEL in InDesign CC:

[image: Working GREP function]

However, when I plug it into a FindChangeList.txt, it doesn't work:

[image]

I know for a fact that the list file is being called correctly and works - so it's not anything to do with that. (If I change it to TEXT and change "2+2" to "2 + 2" the script runs perfectly.)

What is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi LazarusBlack, welcome to GD.SE. Is there any reason why you can not use find `\+` and replace with `\s+\s`?

Comment: Yes. Because I have multiple formats of the "+" plus in the text.

Example: I need to convert every "2+2" to "2 + 2" while leaving "+2" as "+2" and "A+" as "A+" and "+/-" and "+/-".

Answer (score 2):

My friends found the answer on this thread:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2207571

I needed to use double backslash in the text file.

So this works!

```
{findWhat:"(\\d)(\\+)(\\d)"}    
{changeTo:"$1\\s$2\\s$3"}
```

Thanks to everyone who tired.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching every `\+` preceded by a number `(?<=\d)` and followed by a number `(?=\d)`:

`(?<=\d)\+(?=\d)`

and change it for `\s+\s`

[image]

Comment: Nice try, but it behaves just like my script above. 
It works in the FIND/CHANGE panel but not in the FindChangeList.txt file.

Comment: To be clear, your script works just as you show - but only in the FIND/CHANGE panel you are showing me in the animation. 

Can you show me it working in the FindChangeList.txt file?